# Issue a redirect (HTTP 302) to act on _top frame without using Java script

Tags: http-redirect, noscript, forms, asp.net, http-post

I need to redirect the top frame on a form post and it should work irrespective of javascript and across all major browsers.

I can redirect to a page with a link and its target attribute set & and asking the users to click the link.

But would like to know whether I can do it in a 302 Response itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A 302 (or 301, or 303) response only specifies that the browser has to look elsewhere for the requested document (as specified by the `Location` header). The concept of browser frames is completely outside the scope of HTTP.

However, browser frames are defined in HTML, and so is the `target` property on `form` elements:

```
<form action="/somescript?x=y" method="POST" target="_top">
```

This will make the form submit to the _top frame, which means "use the full browser window". This is supported across all modern (and most older, e.g. IE4) browsers and does not require JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. But problem is, I need to pop out of frame on success conditions and remain inside the frame and on same page for error conditions.

Comment: Can't do that without JS - I'd post via AJAX in that case. If "no JS" is a hard, immovable requirement, then "cannot do that" is the answer. Could you go the JS way, and use your "click to redirect" link in a <noscript> tag?

Comment: I think, I will end up doing that. Thanks for the clarification.